# Doubt in section 5.7 of Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra

In section 5.7 (*The Grassman Ring*) of Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*, the authors write (on page 174)

> The proof of the lemma following equation $(5\text{-}36)$ shows that for any $r$-linear form $L$ and any permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dots,r\}$ $$\pi_r(L_\sigma) = \operatorname{sgn}{\sigma}\ \pi_r(L)$$

It is not clear to me how the given equation follows from the proof of the lemma following equation $(5\text{-}36)$. Can someone explain the above statement to me?

The relevant lemma and notations are given below.

---

**Notations and definitions**

Let $V$ be a free module of rank $n$ over a commutative ring $K$ with identity. We denote the space of all $r$-linear forms on $V$ by $M^r(V)$ and the space of all alternating $r$-linear forms by $\Lambda^r(V)$. For $L \in M^r(V)$ and any permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dots,r\}$, we obtain another $r$-linear function $L_\sigma$ by defining $$L_\sigma(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r) = L(\alpha_{\sigma 1},\dots,\alpha_{\sigma r})$$ for all $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r) \in V^r$. For each $L \in M^r(V)$, we define the alternating $r$-linear function $\pi_r L$ by $$\pi_r L = \sum_\sigma (\operatorname{sgn} \sigma) L_\sigma$$ where the sum is over all permutations $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dots,r\}$.

---

***Lemma.*** $\pi_r$ is a linear transformation from $M^r(V)$ into $\Lambda^r(V)$. If $L$ is in $\Lambda^r(V)$ then $\pi_r L = r! L$.

*Proof.* Let $\tau$ be any permutation of $\{1,\dots,r\}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
(\pi_r L)(\alpha_{\tau 1},\dots,\alpha_{\tau r}) &= \sum_\sigma (\operatorname{sgn} \sigma)\ L(\alpha_{\tau \sigma 1}, \dots, \alpha_{\tau \sigma r}) \\
&= (\operatorname{sgn} \tau) \sum_\sigma (\operatorname{sgn} \tau\sigma)\ L(\alpha_{\tau \sigma 1},\dots,\alpha_{\tau \sigma r}).
\end{align}
$$
As $\sigma$ runs (once) over all permutations of $\{1,\dots,r\}$, so does $\tau\sigma$. Therefore,
$$
(\pi_r L)(\alpha_{\tau 1},\dots,\alpha_{\tau r}) = (\operatorname{sgn} \tau)(\pi_r L)(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r).
$$
Thus, $\pi_r L$ is an alternating form.

If $L$ is in $\Lambda^r(V)$, then $L(\alpha_{\sigma 1},\dots,\alpha_{\sigma r}) = (\operatorname{sgn} \sigma) L(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r)$ for each $\sigma$; hence $\pi_r L= r! L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of the lemma shows that $$\pi_r(L_\tau) = \operatorname{sgn}{\tau}\ \pi_r L$$
Why? We first note that $(N_{\tau})_{\sigma} = N_{\sigma \tau}$ (stated explicitly in the subchapter)

So we have:

\begin{align}
\pi_r (L_\tau)(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r) 
&= (\sum_\sigma (\operatorname{sgn}{\sigma})(L_\tau)_\sigma)(\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{r})\\
&= (\sum_\sigma (\operatorname{sgn}{\sigma})(L_{\sigma \tau}))(\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{r})\\
&= (\sum_\sigma (\operatorname{sgn}{\sigma})(L_{\sigma}))(\alpha_{ \tau 1},\dots,\alpha_{ \tau r})\\
&= \pi_r (L)(\alpha_{\tau 1},\dots,\alpha_{\tau r})
.
\end{align}

And the rest follows exactly as in the proof of the lemma (stated also in question above).

Maybe an important point to note :

$(\pi_r L)_\tau (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_r) \neq (\pi_r L) (\alpha_{\tau 1},...,\alpha_{\tau r})$.

Answer (score 2):

The proof of the lemma shows that for $L \in M^r(V)$ and $\tau$ a permutation of $\{1,\dots,r\}$, we have $$(\pi_r L)_\tau = (\operatorname{sgn}{\tau}) (\pi_r L).$$ This precisely says that $\pi_r L \in \Lambda^r(V)$, which is the statement of the lemma. (As an aside, note that the authors are implicitly assuming that $K$ is a ring in which $1+1 \neq 0$; for more details, see [Why is $\pi_r(L)$ a linear transformation into $\Lambda^r(V)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1140462/279515).)

This is not the same as $\pi_r(L_\sigma) = \operatorname{sgn}{\sigma}\ \pi_r L$, so this does not follow from the proof of the lemma.

---

To prove the given identity, let $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r) \in V^r$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
\pi_r (L_\sigma)(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r) &= \sum_\tau (\operatorname{sgn}{\tau})L_\sigma(\alpha_{\tau 1},\dots,\alpha_{\tau r})\\
&= \sum_{\tau} (\operatorname{sgn}{\tau})L(\alpha_{\tau\sigma 1},\dots,\alpha_{\tau\sigma r})\\
&= (\operatorname{sgn}{\sigma})\sum_{\tau}(\operatorname{sgn}{\tau\sigma})L(\alpha_{\tau\sigma 1},\dots,\alpha_{\tau\sigma r}).
\end{align}
$$
As $\tau$ runs (once) over all the permutations of $\{ 1,\dots,r \}$, so does $\tau\sigma$. Therefore,
$$
\pi_r(L_\sigma)(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r) = (\operatorname{sgn} \sigma)(\pi_r L)(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r).
$$
Since $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r)$ was an arbitrary element of $V^r$, we have
$$
\pi_r (L_\sigma) = \operatorname{sgn}{\sigma}\ \pi_r(L).
$$

---

One can see that the idea of this proof is the same as in the proof of the lemma. Perhaps that was what the authors meant in their statement.

Comment: I agree. Hoffman & Kunze appear to be meaning this, but saying something else.

Comment: I would say that what the proof of the lemma shows is actually showing $\pi_r (L_\tau) = (sgn \tau) (\pi_r(L))$ since we have $\pi_r (L_\tau) (\alpha_1 ,..., \alpha_r) 
= (\sum_{\sigma} (sgn \sigma) (L_\tau)_\sigma) (\alpha_1 ,..., \alpha_r) $ and although stated implicitly here, the authors stated this also again explicitly in the next subchapter that $(N_\tau)_\sigma = N_{\sigma \tau}$ so that

Comment: so that

$\pi_r (L_\tau) (\alpha_1 ,..., \alpha_r) 
= (\sum_{\sigma} (sgn \sigma) (L_{\tau})_\sigma) (\alpha_1 ,..., \alpha_r)
= (\sum_{\sigma} (sgn \sigma) (L_{\sigma \tau})) (\alpha_1 ,..., \alpha_r)
= (\sum_{\sigma} (sgn \sigma) (L_{\sigma})) (\alpha_{\tau 1} ,..., \alpha_ {\tau r})
= (\pi_r L) (\alpha_{\tau 1} ,..., \alpha_ {\tau r}) $ . Note that according to the author, 
$(\pi_r L)_\tau (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_r) \neq (\pi_r L) (\alpha_{\tau 1},...,\alpha_{\tau r})$, I admit that it's confusing at first, but it becomes clear after the explanation in the next chapter.

Comment: @hteica I agree, it's implicit in the proof. I say in my answer that the idea of the proof is the same as in the lemma, too. But it would improve the exposition if this were stated more explicitly here itself. (On the other hand, we have Math SE for ironing out these details. :))

Comment: No, it is not the idea that I'm talking about, what I mean is that the proof is exactly the same, what stated implicitly is the fact that $(N_\tau)_\sigma = N_\sigma \tau$ (in the chapter Multilinear Functions) but explicitly in the chapter Grassman Ring. The proof does not show $(\pi_r L)_\tau = (sgn \tau) (\pi_r L) $ but instead it shows that $\pi_r (L_\tau) = (sgn \tau) (\pi_r L) $ (the details in my previous comments) But I agree with you, they should have stated it explicitly in the lemma itself or before the lemma. :))

Comment: @hteica My point of contention is precisely that the authors implicitly assume that $(N_{\tau})_{\sigma} = N_{\sigma \tau}$. My "fix" of the proof just involves a proof of this identity in a special case.

Comment: Ah I see, I was just focused on the line "This is not the same as (...) , so this does not follow from the proof of the lemma. ", which is not the case.

Comment: @hteica Ah, I understand. If I find a way to word it less ambiguously then I'll edit.

Comment: Ok sure nice. I see that the one who edited the question and gave a comment was also misled.

Comment: @hteica May I suggest that you add an answer to the question? It will be good to have more than one viewpoint.

Comment: Ok done, hopefully it helps.