# How to interchange the two summations and simplify?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

How can we simplify the following summation?
$$\sum_{i=0}^{r-j}\sum_{l=0}^{i+j-1}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{i+j}{i}\binom{r-i-1}{r-j-i}F(r,j,l).$$
Here, $F(r,j,l)$ is independent of $i$. So, how are the limits change when interchanging the summations?

Comment: Note that:
$$0 \leq l \leq i+j-1, ~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~ 0 \leq i \leq r-j.$$
Combining both inequalities, we can see that:
$$0\leq l \leq i+j-1 \leq (r-j)+j-1 = r-1,$$
and from this:
$$0\leq l \leq r-1 ~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~ l - j +1 \leq i \leq r-j.$$
Therefore, a change in order of summation would yield:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{r-j}\sum_{l=0}^{i+j-1} (\ast)=\sum_{l=0}^{r-1}\sum_{i=l-j+1}^{r-j}(\ast),$$
where $(\ast)$ is the term you're summing. (See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876828/how-to-change-the-order-of-summation) Is this what you wanted? If so, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @B.Núñez I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starter. Let $a_{i,j,r}=(-1)^{i-1}\binom{i+j}{i}\binom{r-i-1}{r-j-i}$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{r-j}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{l=0}^{i+j-1}a_{i,j,r}F_{r,j,l}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=j}^r\sum_{l=0}^{i-1}a_{i-j,j,r}F_{r,j,l}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{{0\leq l<i\leq r}\atop{i\geq j}}a_{i-j,j,r}F_{r,j,l}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{l=0}^{r-1}\sum_{i=\max\{j,l+1\}}^ra_{i-j,k,1}F_{r,j,l}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\sum_{l=0}^{j-1}F_{r,j,l}\right)\left(\sum_{i=j}^{r}a_{i-j,j,r}\right)}
> \color{blue}{+\sum_{l=j}^{r-1}F_{r,j,l}\sum_{i=l+1}^ra_{i-j,j,r}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index $i$ of the outer sum to start with $i=j$.
- In (2) we  just write the index region more conveniently without changing anything else.
- In (3)     we exchange the sums.
- In (4) we separate the double sum into two parts, noting that the first term is a product of single sums.