# Can a elementary row operation change the size of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My question is very simple - Can an elementary row operation change the size (eg: $2\times2$ or $3\times 2$) of a matrix?

I think the answer should be no, but while reading Linear Algebra by Hoffman Kunze I stumbled upon this:

> ***Definition.*** An $m\times n$ matrix is said to be an **elementary matrix** if it can be obtained from the $m\times m$ identity matrix by means of a single elementary row operation.

Now, I know of 3 elementary row operations, (adding a multiple of one row to another, multiplying throughout a row by a non zero constant and interchanging two rows) but none of them can change the size of a matrix.

But since this is a highly praised book I can't trust myself as much as I'd like to.

Comment: Typo in the definition. It should be $n=m$.

Comment: Are there on-line errata for Hoffman & Kunze?  or is it too ancient a book for that.

Comment: @Dietrich I disagree that it's necessarily a typo. It could just be an unnecessarily general definition from which it would follow as an easy theorem that elementary matrices are square (since row operations don't change dimensions).

Comment: In any case the elementary matrices are square matrices, either as a consequence of this definition or by dint of a simpler definition.  We intend left multiplication by an elementary matrix to accomplish the result of the elementary row operation.

Comment: @GEdgar Nothing official I think but there's this site post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437253/typos-in-hoffman-and-kunze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Original Answer:

It must be a typo. For another reference, if you look at Horn & Johnson's book [here](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/matrix-analysis-2nd-edition) (chapter 0, section 0.3.3 in the first edition) the authors discuss how elementary row operations can be achieved via left multiplication by *square*  matrices.

**Side note:** If we use the fact that elementary row operations on a matrix $\boldsymbol{M}$ are equivalent to multiplying $\boldsymbol{M}$ on the left by (certain) square matrices, it is easy to determine the effect of elementary row operations on the determinant (recall that, for square matrices, $det(\boldsymbol{UM})=det(\boldsymbol{U})det(\boldsymbol{M})$).

### Update:

I can see it not being a typo if what the authors mean is this:

Elementary row operations can be represented using matrix multiplication. How? Suppose I have a matrix $\boldsymbol{A}\in M_{m\times n}$ and I want to apply any of the three operations. All I have to do is:

- Begin with the identity matrix of size $\boldsymbol{m}$, call it $\boldsymbol{I}_m$.
- Apply whichever of the three elementary row operations you want to $\boldsymbol{I}_m$, call this new matrix $\boldsymbol{I}_{new}$. In other words, if you want to apply an elementary row operation to $\boldsymbol{A}$ you *first* apply it to $\boldsymbol{I}_m$.
- Multiply $\boldsymbol{A}$ on the left by $\boldsymbol{I}_{new}$.

Note that this method for performing elementary row operations essentially begins with the identity matrix $\boldsymbol{I}_m$ and then performs the elementary operation on $\boldsymbol{I}_m$. This might be in line with what the authors meant. Of course, you then need to multiply $\boldsymbol{A}$ by this modified identity matrix which won't change the dimension of $\boldsymbol{A}$.

---

**Example (interchanging to rows):** I want to change the first and third rows of $\boldsymbol{A}\in \mathbb{R}_{3\times5}$.

**Solution:** Multiply:
\begin{align*}
{\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]}_{\boldsymbol{I}_{new}}}\boldsymbol{A},
\end{align*}
this will change the first and third row of $\boldsymbol{A}$.

**Note:** the determinant of $\boldsymbol{I}_{new}$ here is -1. (This can be shown using the Alternating Sums formulation of the determinant).

---

**Example (multiplying a row by a non-zero scalar):** I want to multiply the second row of $\boldsymbol{A}\in \mathbb{C}_{3\times 5}$ by 7/3.

**Solution:** Multiply:
\begin{align*}
{\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 7/3 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]}_{\boldsymbol{I}_{new}}}\boldsymbol{A},
\end{align*}
this will multiply the second row of $\boldsymbol{A}$ by $7/3$.

**Note:** The determinant of $\boldsymbol{I}_{new}$ here is 7/3. (The determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the diagonal entries.)

---

**Example (adding a multiple of one row to another):** I want to add 5 times row 1 to row 2 of $\boldsymbol{A}\in \mathbb{C}_{3\times 5}$.

**Solution:** Multiply:
\begin{align*}
{\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 \\5 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]}_{\boldsymbol{I}_{new}}}\boldsymbol{A},
\end{align*}
this will multiply the first row of $\boldsymbol{A}$ by $5$ and add it to the second row of $\boldsymbol{A}$ leaving the first row unchanged.

**Note:** The determinant of $\boldsymbol{I}_{new}$ here is 1. (The determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the diagonal entries.)

---

Notice that, in *each* of these cases, all that was necessary was to choose the identity matrix of the right dimension (in our case, $3\times3$) and to apply the elementary row operation to this identity matrix. Then, we multiply $\boldsymbol{A}$ on the left by this *new* matrix.

- If we wish to apply *multiple* elementary row operations then we can simply repeat this process sequentially for each operation we apply.
- It is now easy to see *how* elementary row operations change the determinant of a square matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ since the determinant of the product of two matrices is the product of the determinants. Additionally, the determinants of the "$\boldsymbol{I}_{new}$" matrices are easy to compute.
- All these "$\boldsymbol{I}_{new}$" matrices are *nonsingular* (it is easy to see that their determinant is nonzero).