# Typo in Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra book

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading [Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra book](http://uap.unnes.ac.id/ebook/mathematics%20ebook/Algebra/Linear%20Algebra,%202nd%20ed%20-%20Kenneth%20Hoffman,%20Ray%20Kunze,%201971.pdf) and on page 183 they made this claim:

[image]

I think it must be "when its determinant *is* $0$" instead of "when its determinant is different from $0$". Am I right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Very nice catch in a widely used text book. +1\

Comment: It seems that finding typos in H+K is a [common problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437253/typos-in-hoffman-and-kunze)

Comment: This was mentioned in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437253/typos-in-hoffman-and-kunze