# Help with these statements in Hoffman/Kunze's Linear Algebra book

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I'm studying the book [Linear Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135367972) by Hoffman and Kunze and on page 211 they state the following observation about projections:

> Projections can be used to describe direct-sum decompositions of the
> space V. For, suppose $V=W_1\oplus\ldots \oplus W_k$. For each $j$ we
> shall define an operator $E_j$ on $V$. Let $\alpha$ be in $V$, say
> $\alpha = \alpha_1+\ldots+\alpha_k$ with $\alpha_i$ in $W_i$. Define
> $E_j\alpha=\alpha_j$. Then $E_j$ is a well-defined rule. It is easy to
> see that $E_j$ is linear, that the range of $E_j$ is $W_j$, and that
> $E_j^2=E_j$. The null space of $E_j$ is the subspace
>
> $$(W_1+\ldots+W_{j-1}+W_{j+1}+\ldots +W_k)$$

I didn't understand the last line, why $(W_1+\ldots+W_{j-1}+W_{j+1}+\ldots +W_k)$? shouldn't be $$(W_1\oplus\ldots\oplus W_{j-1}\oplus W_{j+1}\oplus\ldots \oplus W_k)$$

**EDIT**

The user @Semiclassical pointed out a possible typo in the book, but the link provided doesn't have any relationship with the statements of my question. Besides that, the page is also different.

Comment: There's a working list of typos in Hoffman & Kunze in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437253/is-there-a-list-of-all-typos-in-hoffman-and-kunze-linear-algebra. In particular, the top-voted answer indicates that there's a typo on page 212: "It should be V=W1⊕⋯⊕Wk." So that may be the issue.

Comment: @Semiclassical nfortunately not. This typo is about another sentence.

Comment: what does the fact that $V$ is the direct sum of $W_i$'s tell you?

Comment: @user8675309 it tells me every vector in $V$ can be represented uniquely as a sum of the $W_i$'s

Comment: in other words it tells you that $V= W_1+...+W_k$ *and* the $W_i$ are *independent*.  Now define $V':=(W_1+\ldots+W_{j-1}+W_{j+1}+\ldots +W_k)$ by independence you also have $V' =(W_1\oplus\ldots\oplus W_{j-1}\oplus W_{j+1}\oplus\ldots \oplus W_k)$

Comment: @user8675309 that's what I thought, then the book has a typo?

Comment: why do you think it is a typo? An equality means the authors may write it either way.